# Converting String to NSDate, wrong time zone

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsdate

How to convert String to NSDate and then back to String?

I tried doing it like this:

```
//String to NSDate
let dateString = "2016-07-07T18:09:41Z"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)

//NSDate to String
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en")
let time = formatter.stringFromDate(date!)
```

And time in my case is 21:09, even though it was 18:09. Setting locale does nothing. I guess I am doing something very wrong, just not sure what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Locale` doesn't set the time zone, it just helps set the format to that of the user's locale and preferences. Explicitly set the `timeZone` to get the results you want. For example, to set the time zone to the system time zone try:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
```